# How to add 'Java Options' in Tomcat on Windows

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

In the Tomcat server properties configuration editor type thing, there's a Java tab. In that tab is a Java Options free-text input control.

What's the format for adding settings in there? I've a hunch its `key=value` but I've also seen `-Dkey=value` and possibly its neither.

Comment: It's Tomcat and **not** TomCat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `-Dkey=value`, these are basically what gets passed to java on what would be the command line.

You can see a number of examples of this in an image search: http://www.manageengine.com/products/applications_manager/help/images/APMInsight/apminsight_apache_tomcat_properties.png